# Trigger parent animation on toggle IsChecked.

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to animate the width of a grid when one of its child toggle buttons is checked. However, when I click the toggle button I get an error, stating 'A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName 'MainGrid'.

Here's the XAML I have thus far:

```
 <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>

            <!--This is the animation-->
            <Storyboard x:Key="CollapseGrid">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.200" Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="16" />
            </Storyboard>

            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CollapseIcon, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}"-->
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="FirstColumn" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" x:Name="LastColumn"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" >

                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="Auto" >


                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Background="#B4BBC1">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4" Margin="4,2,0,0" Text="HOME" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10.667" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="25" Background="#00355A">

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="4" Foreground="Gainsboro" Margin="209,1,30,1" Background="#00355A" Text="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextDecorations="Underline" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="4" Foreground="White" Margin="22,0,0,0" Text="{Binding DatabaseLabel}" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="17" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" >
                        <ToggleButton Name="CollapseIcon" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" Padding="4,0,0,0" Margin="0,19" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Content="&#9664;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="9.333">

                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>

                                    <Style.Triggers>

                                    <!--Here's where I try to call the animation--> 
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CollapseGrid}"  />
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    </Trigger>

                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>

                                </Style>
                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
```

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can not reference a UIElement inside of a style, that is why you are getting the following error 'A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName 'MainGrid'.  You could consider using an EventTrigger or DataTrigger instead.

Comment: I considered using an EventTrigger, but that wouldn't let me tie the animation to the IsChecked property.

Comment: You could use a DataTrigger to bind both items to a similar item, that way you will not have to bind to an uiElement.

Comment: If you want to whip him up an example, just put the trigger (and `BeginStoryboard` declaration as a `DataTrigger` on the `MainGrid` parent bound to `IsChecked, ElementName=CollapseIcon` and remove the `Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid"` from the `Storyboard` and you'll have your solution. I have to run in a sec, no time to throw one together. :)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW. I tried implementing your suggestion, however, now I'm getting a new error: "Cannot animate the 'Width' property on a 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the inner exception." I know this animation is possible as I've gotten it to work with the togglebutton's click event.

Comment: Eh, I'm sure it's just some nuance. It's pretty simple, datatrigger on main grid bound to ischecked of your toggle button (true or false) to beginstoryboard. The storyboard would effect the element it's attached to once you remove targetname which would be maingrid. Sorry brother but I'm not about to attempt an example from my phone lol. If nobody's sorted ya by the time I'm around later I'll throw one out here. Have a great weekend!

Comment: I can definitely understand, thanks for your help. In case it helps, [here's the code I was trying](https://gist.github.com/jekrch/9c01d65d513b89660124)